# SQL - Subtract Business Days from Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I am trying to query my table for records where a date field is between 10 Business Days ago and Today. I am struggling to calculate the date 10 business days ago.

In my case, Holidays don't matter. I only need to include Monday - Friday regardless of holiday / working day.

I found this SQL code which does what I want, but backwards. This calculates the number of business days between two dates and I need to subtract a number and get to a date.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2019-08-26'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I've tried using `DATEADD` but can't figure out any logic to exclude Saturday and Sunday. I also don't want to use a function is I don't absolutely have to. I have not been able to find anything regarding DATEADD online without a function that loops through each day.

Desired Functionality:

```
START DATE: TODAY / GETDATE()
NUMBER OF BUSINESS DAYS: 10

DATEADD(DAY, -10 + CALULATE WEEKEND DAYS?, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Probably the simplest, most flexible, most modular, and most maintainable method is to generate a date table, and simply count the rows between the start and end date, excluding weekend days from the count (e.g. `SELECT COUNT (date_value) FROM calendar_table WHERE (date_value BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AND (day_of_week BETWEEN 1 AND 5)`). To do it mathematically and inline, is likely to be wildly complex by comparison and difficult to verify all the special cases. (Edit: comment redone to fix formatting.)

Comment: If you only care about weekends and ignore holidays, you can use the following formula: `DATEADD(DAY, -7*(@bdays / 5) + @bdays % 5, @start_date)`. Then if the result falls on Saturday subtract 1 day, if it falls on Sunday subtract 2 days.

Comment: There is an error in the above formula but I cannot edit the comment. The correct is: `DATEADD(DAY, -7*(@bdays / 5) - @bdays % 5, @start_date)`.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis I had to modify this a little bit to make it inclusive for the start date (which I forgot to mention - sorry), but IT WORKED after writing a case statement to catch if it ends on a saturday or sunday. Thanks. If you want to type it out as a full answer, I'd gladly accept.

Comment: I'll second Steve's suggestion above.  A date table can be handy and easy/clean in several scenarios such as this.

Comment: Greater than two weeks ago is an easy hard limit just use the expression as a secondary filter.

Comment: Or just if today is Sunday deduct 16 days, Saturday is 15, else 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only care about weekends and not other holidays, it is easy to calculate the number of calendar days from the business days, using the knowledge that there are 5 business days in every calendar week (7 days). If you are OK with a scalar function you can use the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SubBusinessDays(
    @days int,
    @date datetime
) RETURNS int
BEGIN
    SET @days = @days-1; -- number of days are inclusive of the start date

    -- add full weeks and adjust for start date in weekend
    SET @date = DATEADD(DAY, -(@days / 5 * 7) +
                    (CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 
                                      WHEN 0 THEN -1 
                                      WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                                      ELSE 0 END), @date);
    -- at this point @date is a work day

    SET @days = @days % 5;
    RETURN DATEADD(DAY, -@days 
                    + (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 - @days < 2 -- remaining days overlap weekend
                          THEN -2 ELSE 0 END), @date)
    
END
```

If on the other hand you need to work on a table you can use `CROSS APPLY` to do the same in steps as in the following sample:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(StartDate Datetime, BDays int)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT d, ofs
FROM (VALUES ('20190906'), ('20190907'), ('20190908'), ('20190909'), ('20190910')) AS sd(d)
    CROSS JOIN 
     (VALUES (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) AS bd(ofs)


SELECT StartDate, BDays, EndDate
FROM @t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT BDaysMinus1 = BDays-1) x1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndDateTemp = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                        -((BDaysMinus1 / 5) * 7) 
                                        +(CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7  
                                            WHEN 0 THEN -1 
                                            WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                                            ELSE 0 END), StartDate),
                        RemainingDays = BDaysMinus1 % 5) x2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -RemainingDays +(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EndDateTemp) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 - RemainingDays < 2 
                                        THEN -2 ELSE 0 END), EndDateTemp)) x3
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work correctly in all cases. Haven't reviewed why, but this doesn't work for what I was trying to accomplish. Just wanted to point it out.
Set days = 10:
Set date = '2023-06-27 09:29:55.677'

Comment: Fixed the code to handle multiples of 5 days and laso handle the case when remaining days cross a weeken boundary

Answer (score 0):

Try this Recursive CTE as shown below-

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE= GETDATE(), 
    @NumberOfDays INT= 10;


WITH cte
AS 
(               
    SELECT @start_date AS date_

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, date_) AS DATE)
    FROM cte
    WHERE date_ >= DATEADD(
        DD,
        -(@NumberOfDays   + (@NumberOfDays/7+1)*3), 
        --Generating a approximate number consediring  
        --Number Of Business Day + Approximate Week Ends for that days
        @start_date
    )
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT Date_,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_ DESC) RN
    FROM cte 
    WHERE DATENAME(dw, Date_) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

SELECT Date_ 
FROM CTE2
WHERE  RN = @NumberOfDays
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Seems to be working great for adding business days. I need it to subtract business days. Can this be modified to go backwards starting at `GETDATE()`?

Comment: You can set any date in place of GETDATE()

Comment: I understand that. But I need to start at `GETDATE()` (Today) and count backwards to whatever number (`@NumberOfDays`) business days. Your solution works for starting at `GETDATE()` and counting forwards whatever number of business days.

Comment: Ohh, I understand.  I have updated the code and it should work. As i updated the code using mobile, i cannot check the syntax but the logic is set accordingly. I can check if any syntax issue is there or not later. But i hope this is ok now. @dvo

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I found the accepted answer really useful. I have taken the code and made a minor change. Here is a version but to add working days to a date, rather than subtract them. Hope it helps someone. Thanks to P.Kouvarakis.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(StartDate Datetime, BDays int)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT d, ofs
FROM (VALUES ('20220722'), ('20220719'), ('20190907'), ('20190908'),('20190909'), ('20190910')) AS sd(d)
        CROSS JOIN 
         (VALUES (1), (3), (8), (9), (10), (11)) AS bd(ofs)

SELECT StartDate, BDays, EndDate
FROM @t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndDateTemp = DATEADD(DAY, ((BDays / 5) * 7 + BDays % 5), DATEADD(DAY, (CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 WHEN 6 THEN 2 WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), StartDate))) x2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndDate     = DATEADD(DAY, (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EndDateTemp) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 IN (0,1) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END), EndDateTemp)) x3
ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC;
```